# How long does it take a journal to assign an associate editor?

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

I submitted my paper more than a month and a half ago and the journal still hasn't assigned an editor yet. It passed initial validation, though. I found out that for others, it generally takes 1-2 weeks to pass initial validation and assign an editor.
I reached out to the editorial office and they said they were finding editors and asked me to recommend some. I recommended 8 editors more than three weeks ago and nothing have changed. Should I withdraw and submit to another journal, or how should I reach out to the editorial office again?
Note: this is about assigning handling editor not reviewers.